# How to add set() values after a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, set

So I have been trying to create a script where it checks a txt file and checks if the name (`new_names_list = {line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('names.txt')}`) from a txt file has been added to a set()(`old_names_list = set()`) and if it not has, it should loop through all names and then afterwards at it in a set(). Meaning it needs to loop through all names (Will provide code so it will be easier to understand) and then add it to a set()

```
import json, time, sys, os, timeit, random, colorama, requests, traceback, multiprocessing, re
from random import choice
import threading


def get_names():

    name_test = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('randomnames.txt')]
    return name_test

def filter(thread, i):
    print(i)

def main():
    old_list = []

    old_names_list = set()

    while True:

        new_names_txt = {line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('names.txt')}

        for new_thread in get_names():

            if not new_names_txt == old_names_list:
                for i in new_names_txt :
                    if not i in old_names_list:
                        threading.Thread(target=filter, args=(new_thread, new_names_txt )).start()
                        if new_thread not in old_list:
                            old_list.append(new_thread)

            elif new_thread not in old_list:
                threading.Thread(target=filter, args=(new_thread, new_names_txt)).start()
                old_list.append(new_thread)

        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(1, 3)
            print('No changes!')
            time.sleep(randomtime)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Keyboard - Interrupted' )
        sys.exit()


randomnames.txt

Alejandro  
Tisha  
Eleni  
Milton  
Jeanice  
Billye  
Vicki  
Shelba  
Valorie  
Penelope  
Mellissa  
Ambrose  
Retta  
Milissa  
Charline  
Brittny  
Ehtel  
Hilton  
Hobert  
Lakendra  
Silva  
Lawana  
Sidney  
Janeen  
Audrea  
Orpha  
Peggy  
Kay  
Marvis  
Tia  
Randy  
Cary  
Santana  
Roma  
Mandi  
Tyrone  
Felix  
Maybelle  
Leonia  
Micha  
Idalia  
Aleida  
Elfrieda  
Velia  
Cassondra  
Drucilla  
Oren  
Kristina  
Madison  
Dia  


names.txt

Alejandro
Tisha
Eleni
Dia
Hobert
```

My problem is that in `if not new_names_txt  == old_names_list:` we find the names (`new_names_txt  = {line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('names.txt')}`) that are in names.txt. Meaning if that if statement is True. We should loop that names that picks up as `i` and loop through all `new_thread` and once it's done it should continue to do the next name (`new_names_txt`) until there is no more names (`new_names_txt`) to compare. What do I need to do to make this problem to solve?

Comment: It seems that `old_names_list` is *always* an empty set. Aren't you forgetting to populate it somewhere?

Comment: Oh true, I do forgot to add the i somewhere. Where should I apply it when the for loop 'new thread' is finished? I think this is the problem I am having which I believe I mentioned (hopefully:( ) @MartinFrodl

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, could you be more specific? *...script where it checks a txt file (**which file?**) and checks if the name (**which name?**) from a txt file (**which txt file?**) has been added to a set() (**which set?**) and if it not has, it should loop through all names (**which names?**) and then afterwards at it in a set() (**which set?**)*

Comment: Okey, I have now edited which I hope is abit better now. Basically my idea was to loop through all random names `get_names():` using `for new_thread in get_names():` - We check if the if-statement is True. if it is - We take the first name from names.txt and loop through whole `for new_thread in get_names():` and when its finished, I want it to add the name to `old_names_list = set()` and then continue with second name from names.txt and repeat like this until there is no more names in names.txt. @MartinFrodl

Comment: What is the difference between `old_list` and `old_names_list`? What is each of them supposed to contain?

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere `new_names_list = {line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('names.txt')}` is a set not a list, maybe you want to rename that variable.

Comment: Oh, oh okey, I will change it to new_names_txt @Guimoute

Comment: @MartinFrodl old_list was supposed to save the `new_thread` values and old_names_list is supposed to save `if not i in old_names_list:`